# Increment JProgressBar

Tags: java, eclipse, swing

- First time using Swing
- I have a method that creates KML files for each vessel object in Vessel
- I'm trying to have a Jprogress bar increment as each file is produced
- Currently the Jprogress bar does not increment till the method has completed and the bar is then filled [empty -> full, no increment]

  ```
  JProgressBar progressBar = new JProgressBar();
  progressBar.setBounds(237, 142, 172, 22);
  frmThis.getContentPane().add(progressBar);
  progressBar.setValue(0);

  JButton btnGenerateKml = new JButton("Generate KML");
  btnGenerateKml.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 12));
  btnGenerateKml.setBounds(237, 108, 172, 23);
  btnGenerateKml.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

          progressBar.setMaximum(vessels.size());

          JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
          fc.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
          int returnVal = fc.showSaveDialog(frmThis);
          try {
              if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
                  File file = fc.getSelectedFile();
                  int value =0; 
                  for(Entry<Long, Vessel> entry : vessels.entrySet()){
                      if(!entry.getValue().getCoordinates().isEmpty()){
                          FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter(file.getPath()+"\\"+entry.getKey()+
                                  ".kml");
                          BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream); 
                          out.write("<kml>"); 
                          out.write("<Folder>");

                          out.write("<Placemark>");
                          out.write("<name>"+entry.getKey()+"</name>");
                          out.write("<LineString>");
                          out.write("<extrude>1</extrude>"); 
                          out.write("<tessellate>1</tessellate>");
                          out.write("<altitudeMode>clampToGround</altitudeMode>");
                          out.write("<coordinates>");
                          for(int i=0; i<entry.getValue().getCoordinates().size(); i++){ //path creation 
                              out.write(entry.getValue().getCoordinates().get(i).getLongitude()+","+
                                      entry.getValue().getCoordinates().get(i).getLatitude()+" ");
                          }
                          out.write("</coordinates>");
                          out.write("</LineString>");
                          out.write("</Placemark>");

                          for(int j=0; j<entry.getValue().getCoordinates().size(); j++){ //point creation 
                              out.write("<Placemark>");
                              out.write("<name>"+entry.getValue().getCoordinates().get(j).coordinates()+"</name>");
                              out.write("<tessellate>1</tessellate>");
                              out.write("<altitudeMode>clampToGround</altitudeMode>");
                              out.write("<Point>");
                              out.write("<coordinates>");
                              out.write(entry.getValue().getCoordinates().get(j).getLongitude()+","+
                                      entry.getValue().getCoordinates().get(j).getLatitude());
                              out.write("</coordinates>");
                              out.write("</Point>");
                              out.write("</Placemark>");
                          }

                          out.write("</Folder>");
                          out.write("</kml>");
                          out.close();


                          progressBar.setValue(value);
                          value++; 


                      }
                  }
              }
          } catch (IOException e) {
              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
      }
  });
  frmThis.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
  frmThis.getContentPane().add(btnGenerateKml);
  ```
- I've been looking at the oracle how-to
- sorry for long code snippet, max is initialized when button is clicked(max is generally unknown, if button is clicked then MAX has been established), value is set to 0 before for loop and then incremented after each vessel.

Comment: The easiest way is probably a [`SwingWorker`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/).

Comment: Your loop is running on the event thread. You call progressBar.setValue() each time through the loop, but the thread has no opportunity to act on it until your method ends. You should do the body of your actionListener in a separate thread, and use a Runnable  - via SwingUtilities.invokeLater() - to update the progressBar.

Comment: But your original code is still being run on the event thread, blocking it from handling any of the updates. Put it in a SwingWorker as recommended by Catalina Island.